# Update a dictionary of item in Python using bottle framework

Tags: python, rest, dictionary, put, bottle

I am doing crud rest API in Python with bottle framework and I am having trouble updating an item by id in a dictionary. So far I have done create, read, and delete.

Here is my dictionary:

```
items = [
    {"id": "1", "name": "a", "lastname": "a"},
    {"id": "2", "name": "b", "lastname": "b"},
    {"id": "3", "name": "c", "lastname": "c"}, 
]
```

And here is my route:

```
from bottle import get, post, run, redirect, request, response, view, put

@put("/items/<item_id>")
def updated_item(item_id):
    for item in items:
        if item["id"] == item_id:
        new_name = request.forms.get("name")
        new_lastname = request.forms.get("lastname")
            
        #(I need some help here)
    
    return redirect("/items")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate on items, if `items` index is constant. That means that there is mapping between the index in the `list` and the `item["id"]`:

```
@put("/items/<item_id>")
def updated_item(item_id):
    
    new_name = request.forms.get("name")
    new_lastname = request.forms.get("lastname")
        
    items[int(item_id) - 1] = {"id": item_id, "name": new_name, "lastname": "new_lastname"}

return redirect("/items")
```

If you delete items, just keep an empty element to keep the order:

```
@delete("/items/<item_id>"):
def delete_item(item_id):
    
    items[int(item_id)] = {}
```

Of course, if `id` is arbitrary, this won't work, e.g.:

```
items = [
{"id": "12", "name": "a", "lastname": "a"},
{"id": "21", "name": "b", "lastname": "b"},
{"id": "53", "name": "c", "lastname": "c"},  
]
```

If this is the case, you should consider using an in memory database (e.g. SQLite) which is great at housekeeping of records like you just showed.
The database will then replace `items` (well, it's going to be a table).

Comment: The id is going to be arbitrary since I am going to use uuid. So I just want to update the name and the lastname by id. I am not using a database. I want to learn first how to do with hardcoded data. What can I do in this case? And also can I use PUT as a method in HTML form or I should use POST instead? Thanks in advance

Comment: HTML uses POST, so that goes in the form. As for using a pure data structure instead of a database: consider putting items inside a dict. Using a list for searching data is going to be cumbersome.

Comment: as for now I am using a dictionary. Is there any way you can help by giving me an example on how to update an item in a dictionary by its ID. And in this case I mean the ID is arbitrary so it will be some thing like: 
items = [{"id": "49-hg4-566g", "name": "a", "lastname": "a"}]. And should I use @ put or @ post method on the backend since I will be using post on the HTML form?

Comment: Instead of using a list of dictionaries, you should use a dictionary of dictionaries, with the ID used as the key for each data record: `{"acd-123": {"name": "joe", "lastname": "doe"}, {"ace-765": {"name": "Ruth",...}}`. Essential, this is how a nosql database would work. Hope this helps.

Comment: that will definitely help, but you gave me earlier the example of: `items[int(item_id) - 1] = {"id": item_id, "name": new_name, "lastname": "new_lastname"}`. Could you show me how I could update this time the dictionary of a dictionary as you suggested `{"acd-123": {"name": "joe", "lastname": "doe"}, {"ace-765": {"name": "Ruth",...}}` using the ID `acd-123` as a key? I have been struggling with this the entire day and I can't find any solution. Thanks again in advance

Comment: `items[item_id] = {"id": item_id, "name": new_name, "lastname": new_lastname}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242162/discussion-between-elisha-and-oz123).